# Not able to send Object to rest API in angular 6

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript

I am consuming Rest API and wants to save User Data, i am able to hit the API but not able to send the object. Its showing null in API.

I checked my console and network, its showing the angular application URL not the API URL.

```
export class UserService {
  url = 'http://localhost:8085/api/employees';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  userData(user: User): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('id', '5').
    set('userName', 'Bisnu').set('salary', '100').set('department', 'IT').set('password', 'mohan')
    .set('firstName', 'Bisnu').set('lastName', 'Biswal');
    const newUser = {
      userName: 'Bisnu',
      salary: 100,
      password: 'mohan',
      department: 'IT',
      firstName: 'Bisnu',
      lastName: 'Mohan'
    };

    console.log(newUser);
    console.log(this.url);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url, newUser);
  }
}
```

and from component i am calling this service

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.user);
    this.userService.userData(this.user).subscribe(
      data => console.log("success", data),
      error => console.error("Error!",error)
    );
    this.resetForm();
  }
}
```

Browser console i checked it is as below, which is wrong.

[image]

the controller is as below

[image]

The User model is as below

[image]

Comment: are you able hit API Call ?

Comment: yes Shahid, able to hit API but values are showing as null, not able to identify what is wrong. I hardcoded the values but still null values. The screenshot i have given, in that request URL is showing wrong and method also is showing "GET", but i have done post.

Comment: If you are able to hit the API with a null value then the screenshot you have shown us must be a different request. If your API is hit there must be a request made to it. It may be useful to show the code from your API where the null value appears.

Comment: That's a simple rest API

Comment: i have faced this kind of  problem. please verify your data type with back-end . if you are sending the float value or string value from angular side and in api side data type is int then you will get null value. please verify your data type in your code i can  see, on one place  salary is string and second place you are sending value as int

Comment: Could you show the `User` model?

Comment: @UncleDave i have copied that in the question

Comment: Sorry, I meant the backend `User` model.

Comment: @mohan could you put `@RequestBody` infront of the `User` argument in the backend? `public void saveEmployee(@RequestBody User employee)`

Comment: @mohan what are you trying to achieve, which format do you want to send data  ,  json object or formdata  which one is it ? please specify

Comment: thnx guys, spelling mistake was there. Now able to do and got the values.

Comment: I am new to Angular 6.thnx @UncleDave,@Joel Joseph,@Shahid Islam,@Bhargil Joshi

Answer (score -1):

Try this, backend object and your newuser object does not match.

```
    userData(user: User): Observable<any> {
          user.Id :1;
          user.userName: 'Bisnu';
          user.salary: 100;
          user.password: 'mohan';
          user.department: 'IT';
          user.firstName: 'Bisnu';
          user.lastName: 'Mohan';

        return this.http.post<any>(this.url, user);
      }
```

Comment: Could you explain this answer?

Comment: This is not valid javascript. Furthermore your explanation does not make sense, HOW does the backend object and `newuser` object not match when you haven't seen the backend object as it has not yet been posted by the OP? Further to that even if your code was valid it would have no difference to the code originally posted by OP, other than the fact your code would explode if a null `user` was passed as an argument.

Comment: @UncleDave check in UserModel, he is not passing "Id" parameter

Comment: @BhargilJoshi able to hit the API now,

userData(user: User): Observable<User> {
    
    user.Id = 10;
    user.UserName = 'Bisnu';
    user.Salary = '100';
    user.Password = 'mohan';
    user.Department = 'IT';
    user.FirstName = 'Bisnu';
    user.LastName = 'Mohan';

    console.log(user);
  return this.http.post<User>(this.url,user);

Comment: i can see the values in request payload, but in API those values are showing as null, do i have to do anything for conversion or what?

Comment: @mohan In C# we use a method

public void saveEmployee([Frombody] User employee)

check how [Frombody] work for you